# PHP form is displayed but doesn't do anything besides clear itself when submitted

Tags: php

My HTML form is displayed by the else portion of my if statement. The if portion checks to see if the form was posted to SELF then should echo the form inputs. Instead, the form clears itself and echoes nothing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("I am an alert box!"); // this is the message in ""
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
//Display output once form submitted  
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//debug
echo '<script>myfunction()</script>';

// define variables and set to empty values
$firstname = 'test';
$middlename = 'test';
$lastname = 'test';
$email = 'test';
$phone = 'test';
$dd214 = 'test';
$description = 'test';
$firstnameErr = 'test';
$middlenameErr = 'test';
$lastnameErr = 'test';
$emailErr = 'test';
$phoneErr = 'test';
$dd214Err = 'test';
$descriptionErr = 'test';

if (empty($_POST["FIRSTNAME"])) {
    $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
} 
else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
        $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }

    else {
        $firstname = test_input($_POST["FIRSTNAME"]);
    }
}


if (empty($_POST["MIDDLENAME"])) {
    $middlenameErr = "Middle name is required";
} 
else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$middlename)) {
        $middlenameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    else {
         $middlename = test_input($_POST["MIDDLENAME"]);
    }
}


if (empty($_POST["LASTNAME"])) {
    $lastnameErr = "Last name is required";
} 
else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
        $lastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    else {
         $lastname = test_input($_POST["LASTNAME"]);
    }
}


if (empty($_POST["EMAILADDRESS"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
}
else {
if (!filter_var($_POST["EMAILADDRESS"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $emailErr = "Please enter a valid email address";
}
else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["EMAILADDRESS"]);
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["PHONENUMBER"])) {
    $phoneErr = "Phone number is required";
}
else {
    if(!filter_var($_POST["PHONENUMBER"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) {
        $phoneErr = "Please enter a valid phone number";
    }
    else{
        if ((strlen($_POST['PHONENUMBER']) >= 10) && (strlen($_POST['PHONENUMBER']) <= 14)){
            $phone = test_input($_POST["PHONENUMBER"]);
        }
        else {
            $phoneErr = "Please enter a valid phone number";
        }
    }
}


if (empty($_POST["DD214"])) {
  $dd214Err = "DD214 is required";
}
else {
    if (!get_mime_type($dd214)) {
        $dd214Err = "Please ensure your DD214 is a jpeg or pdf file.";
    }
    else {
        $dd214 = test_input($_POST["DD214"]);
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["DESCRIPTION"])) {
$descriptionErr = "Description is required";
} 
else {
$description = test_input($_POST["DESCRIPTION"]);
}

echo "Results:\r\n";
echo $firstname;
echo $middlename;
echo $lastname;
echo $email;
echo $phone;
echo $dd214;
echo $description;
echo $firstnameErr;
echo $middlenameErr;
echo $lastnameErr;
echo $emailErr;
echo $phoneErr;
echo $dd214Err;
echo $descriptionErr;
}

else {
    echo "<form name='contactform' method='post' autocomplete='ON'>";
    echo "Please enter your full name:";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>First*";
            echo "<br>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='FIRSTNAME' required maxlength='30' autofocus>\r\n";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>Middle*";
            echo "<br>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='MIDDLENAME' required maxlength='30'>\r\n";
                echo "<td>Last*";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='LASTNAME' required maxlength='20'>\r\n";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Email address:";
                echo "<br>";
            echo "<input type='email' name='EMAILADDRESS' required pattern='^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$'>\r\n";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "Phone number:";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='PHONENUMBER' required pattern='^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$' maxlength='14'>\r\n";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "Please upload a PDF or JPEG of your DD214:";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<input type='file' name='DD214' accept='.pdf, .jpeg, .jpg' style='color:firebrick;'>";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "Brief description of your legal issue (1000 char max):";
            echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='DESCRIPTION' required maxlength='1000' style:'width:40%;height:15%;'>\r\n";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<p>Notice: Do not send confidential information using this form. Use of this form does not create an attorney-client relationship and therefore is not considered privileged and confidential information. Until an attorney-client relationship is created by agreement of the parties, anything submitted could be subjected to court-ordered disclosure.</p>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' style='color: #DDDDDD;'>";
    echo "</form>";

    //Helper Functions
    function get_mime_type($file) {
    $mtype = false;
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    } elseif (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
    $mtype = mime_content_type($file);
    } 
    if ($mtype == application/pdf || $mtype == image/jpeg)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the else portion must be working, because it displays the form HTML that's echoed if POST has not occurred. What I can't figure out is why the echoes showing the POSTed form fields don't appear. Ultimately this will be a contact form, but I need to at least get it working for some purposes before I finish that portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the name attribute to the sumbit button

```
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' style='color: #DDDDDD;'>";
```

When a form is submitted to the server, the data from the form is included in an HTTP request. The data is packaged as a series of name-value pairs. The name for each name-value pair is the name attribute of each input, and the value is the user-entered (or pre-specified) value. Without the name attribute, an  element cannot provide its value to the server on form submission.

Read more: https://html.com/attributes/input-name/#ixzz5y9XVUvy4

Comment: Ugh, I wondered that but I didn't see it in any of the example code I was looking at. I should have just tried it. Thank you!